# Extract column names from df as a vector - or copy / paste column names to new df?

Tags: r, rbind

is there a way to extract column names from a df and convert into a vector?  In fact, what I am trying to do is rbing two df's, the second has no names so returning a name matching error?  Maybe there is an easier way to copy the df1 column names to df2 so rbind will work?

Comment: Try `names(df2) <- names(df1)`

Comment: In general, `names(df)` or `colnames(df)` both work to get the column names as a vector. And as the earlier comment shows, you can use them to modify the names as well, e.g., `names(df) <- vector_of_new_names` or `names(df)[3] <- "new name for third column"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one line:

```r
df3 <- rbind(df1, setNames(df2, names(df1)))
```

Comment: Greaty, thank you. Perfect